# Django admin/doc/views/ all blank or broken

Tags: django-admin, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to use Django's built-in admin docs feature to make writing templates easier. Supposedly if you go to /admin/docs/views you should get documentation for every view in your application. I see a list, but none of the links work:

-) Any view listed that's related to my application just goes to a blank page with nothing but the name of the view as a header.

-) The views related to admin all give me Django 404 errors when I click on them, *except* those that are related to the docs itself. The docs-related links also give me blank pages. (i.e. clicking /admin/doc/filters gives a blank page with nothing but "django.contrib.admindocs.views.template_filter_index" as a title, but clicking /admin/auth/user gives me a Django 404 error

The 404 errors lead me to suspect my URLconf is wrong, but all I did was uncomment the built-in lines. The relevant sections read:

```
# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

And I have no idea what to make of the blank pages. Do I need to provide some extra meta information somewhere, like I know you need to provide the get_absolute_url on models for some of the admin features to work right?

Even if no one knows the answer, any documentation on the admin docs feature would be useful -- I've been Google all over (and searching StackOverflow) and this feature seems very little-documented.

Thanks!

Comment: I ran into the same problem, but discovered only my views wrapped in decorators were broken. See [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5701) for more details. It claims the issue is fixed, but I'm still seeing it in a Django 1.3 project. If you look at some of the dupe tickets listed in that ticket, there are some work-arounds suggested.

Comment: [This approach](https://gist.github.com/4674070) fixed it for me.

Comment: @Tom I stumbled in this problem again now, Django Rest Framework uses the `@APIView` decorator and every view that uses it is broken in the admin docs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `'django.contrib.admindocs'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. It should already be there and commented out. Though it would be nice if the comment in `urls.py` mentioned it ... [Source](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/7fdbb7548d2665fe).

Answer (score 0):

I've *never* looked at the views admin doc pages before -- I've never had a need to.  B4ut you're right, they seem to be -- lacking in potential features.

If you give your views functions docstrings (documentation), that content will appear on your "blank pages".

Most -- no, all -- of the admin sites views are actually decorated member methods of `admin.sites.AdminSite`.  I looked around, and a view of mine which uses a decorator also suffers from the 404.

The view responsible for view details starts:

```
def view_detail(request, view):
    if not utils.docutils_is_available:
        return missing_docutils_page(request)

    mod, func = urlresolvers.get_mod_func(view)
    try:
        view_func = getattr(import_module(mod), func)
    except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        raise Http404
    title, body, metadata = utils.parse_docstring(view_func.__doc__)
    ...
```

You can see it tries to import the view to get info from it; if the view is actually a decorator (which probably used an internal function to wrap the real view), it won't be able to import it.  eg, if you do `from django.contrib.admin.sites import index` in a django shell, you'll get an ImportError, whereas `django.contrib.admin.site.index` (note the singular `site`) is a:

`<bound method AdminSite.index of <django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite object at 0x...>>`

Further, that last line in my snippet seems to indicate that there's a capability for finer control over what shows up on those pages, if you care to figure out the template that `util.parse_docstring` uses.